# Python Concordance program - alphabetical order

Tags: python, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to write a program that displays a concordance for a file.  It should output the unique words and their frequencies in alphabetical order.  This is what I have, but it's not working.  Tips?

FYI - I know NOTHING about computer programming!! I'm taking this class to satisfy a high school math endorsement requirement.

```
f = open(raw_input("Enter a filename: "), "r")
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for line in f:
  line = line.strip()
  line = line.lower()
  line = line.split()
  linenum += 1

for word in line:
    word = word.strip()
    word = word.lower()

    if not word in myDict:
        myDict[word] = []

    myDict[word].append(linenum)


print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Line Number")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, myDict(key))
```

Comment: what exactly is the output for a given input? Simply saying 'it doesn't work' isn't very helpful without telling us exactly why it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use myDict[key] for getting from a dictionary. And since that's a list, you need to use sum(myDict[key]) for frequency (count)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use myDict[key] for getting from a dictionary. And since that's a list, you need to use sum(myDict[key]) for frequency (count)

```
f = "HELLO HELLO HELLO WHAT ARE YOU DOING"
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for word in f.split():
    if not word in myDict:
        myDict[word] = []

    myDict[word].append(linenum)


print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Frequency")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, len(myDict[key]))
```

Results in:

```
Word            Frequency
ARE            : 1
DOING          : 1
HELLO          : 3
WHAT           : 1
YOU            : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You had your indentation wrong. Second loop was outside of first, so it was working only on the last line. (you should consider using 4 spaces to better see it). You also had your printing wrong and you were printing line numbers, not word count.

```
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.split()
    linenum += 1
    for word in line:
        word = word.strip()
        word = word.lower()

        if not word in myDict:
            myDict[word] = []
        myDict[word].append(linenum)
print "%-15s %5s  %s" %("Word", 'Count', "Line Numbers")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s %5d: %s' % (key, len(myDict[key]), myDict[key])
```

Sample output:

```
Word            Count  Line Numbers
-                   1: [6]
a                   4: [2, 2, 3, 7]
about               1: [6]
alphabetical        1: [4]
```

*Edit* corrected mistakes in code

Comment: This program didn't do as expected. Word is gone and the value for Count is showing more than expected. Try your program and set f="a a all alphabetical an an appeared. arbitrary Bonus: concordance, document each each English, frequencies. generate Given i.e. in in label labeled list numbers occurrence occurrences, of program sentence text that the which will with with word word word write written"

Comment: Come again? I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: May be it was my Python version (2.6.7 or lower) but when I tried the code above and set the value of "f" variable as mentioned in my comment above, it didn't print output as shown by the "Sample output" by you.

Comment: f should be an opened text file object or list of lines

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for concordance ...

https://github.com/jrgosalia/Python/blob/master/problem2_concordance.py

$ python --version
Python 3.5.1

#### library.py

```
def getLines(fileName):
    """ getLines validates the given fileName.
        Returns all lines present in a valid file. """
    lines = ""
    if (fileName != None and len(fileName) > 0 and os.path.exists(fileName)):
        if os.path.isfile(fileName):
            file = open(fileName, 'r')
            lines = file.read()
            if (len(lines) > 0):
                return lines
            else:
                print("<" + fileName + "> is an empty file!", end="\n\n")
        else:
            print("<" + fileName + "> is not a file!", end="\n\n")
    else:
        print("<" + fileName + "> doesn't exists, try again!", end="\n\n")
    return lines
```

#### problem2_concordance.py

```
from library import getLines

# List of English Punctuation Symbols
# Reference : Took maximum puntuations symbols possible from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation_of_English
# NOTE: Apostrophe is excluded from the list as having it or not having it will give always distinct words.
punctuations = ["[", "]", "(", ")", "{", "}", "<", ">", \
         ":", ";", ",", "`", "'", "\"", "-", ".", \
         "|", "\\", "?", "/", "!", "-", "_", "@", \
         "\#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "+", "~", "=" ]

def stripPunctuation(data):
    """ Strip Punctuations from the given string. """
    for punctuation in punctuations:
        data = data.replace(punctuation, " ")
    return data

def display(wordsDictionary):
    """ Display sorted dictionary of words and their frequencies. """
    noOfWords = 0
    print("-" * 42)
    print("| %20s | %15s |" % ("WORDS".center(20), "FREQUENCY".center(15)))
    print("-" * 42)
    for word in list(sorted(wordsDictionary.keys())):
        noOfWords += 1
        print("| %-20s | %15s |" % (word, str(wordsDictionary.get(word)).center(15)))
        # Halt every 20 words (configurable)
        if (noOfWords != 0 and noOfWords % 20 == 0):
            print("\n" * 2)
            input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE ... ")
            print("\n" * 5)
            print("-" * 42)
            print("| %20s | %15s |" % ("WORDS".center(20), "FREQUENCY".center(15)))
            print("-" * 42)
    print("-" * 42)
    print("\n" * 2)

def prepareDictionary(words):
    """ Prepare dictionary of words and count their occurences. """
    wordsDictionary = {}
    for word in words:
        # Handle subsequent Occurences
        if (wordsDictionary.get(word.lower(), None) != None):
            # Search and add words by checking their lowercase version
            wordsDictionary[word.lower()] = wordsDictionary.get(word.lower()) + 1
        # Handle first Occurence
        else:
            wordsDictionary[word.lower()] = 1
    return wordsDictionary

def main():
    """ Main method """
    print("\n" * 10)
    print("Given a file name, program will find unique words and their occurences!", end="\n\n");
    input("Press ENTER to start execution ... \n");

    # To store all the words and their frequencies
    wordsDictionary = {}
    lines = ""
    # Get valid input file
    while (len(lines) == 0):
        fileName = input("Enter the file name (RELATIVE ONLY and NOT ABSOLUTE): ")
        print("\n\n" * 1)
        lines = getLines(fileName)
    # Get all words by removing all puntuations
    words = stripPunctuation(lines).split()
    # Prepare the words dictionary
    wordsDictionary = prepareDictionary(words)
    # Display words dictionary
    display(wordsDictionary)

"""
    Starting point
"""
main()
```

NOTE: You would need library.py too for executing above code, which is also present in same github repository.

Comment: You should add the code into your post above. Having a link which could possibly not exist in the future isn't a good way to answer.

Comment: This was my first post and I tried pasting my code but the editor distorted my code and it isn't able to distinguish between comments and actual code so i created my own github repository so that it can preserve the formatted code. Formatted code is very easy to read. Let me know if i am missing something in pasting code here ...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Counter? That's what it's for:

```
In [8]: s = 'How many times does each word show up in this sentence word word show up up'

In [9]: words = s.split()

In [10]: Counter(words)
Out[10]: Counter({'up': 3, 'word': 3, 'show': 2, 'times': 1, 'sentence': 1, 'many': 1, 'does': 1, 'How': 1, 'each': 1, 'in': 1, 'this': 1})
```

Note: I can't take credit for this specific solution. It comes straight from [Collections Module counter Python Bootcamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHwShNpGrnY)

Answer (score 0):

Concordance for a text file, in alphabetical order;

```
f=input('Enter the input file name: ')
inputFile = open(f,"r")
list={}
for word in inputFile.read().split():
    if word not in list:
        list[word] = 1
    else:
            list[word] += 1
            inputFile.close();
for i in sorted(list):
    print("{0} {1} ".format(i, list[i]));
```